# Can't start foreground service when the application is not running via BroadcastReceiver with USER_PRESENT on Android 13 (MIUI 14)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-13, miui

I can't make my receiver work if the app is not already running (If it's running it works fine)

I have the same problem also with the intent USER_UNLOCKED

I managed to make the receiver work when the app is not running with the BOOT_COMPLETED intent by running in my main activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   ...
   val pref = getSharedPreferences("allow_notify", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
   pref.apply()
   val sp = getSharedPreferences("allow_notify", MODE_PRIVATE)
   if (!sp.getBoolean("protected", false)) {
      val miuiIntent = Intent().setComponent(
         ComponentName(
            "com.miui.securitycenter",
            "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"
         )
      )
      if (packageManager.resolveActivity(miuiIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null) {
         startActivity(miuiIntent)
         sp.edit().putBoolean("protected", true).apply()
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Right now my service onCreate is exactly

```
override fun onCreate() {
   super.onCreate()
   val filter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)
   filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)
   val mReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = StartupReceiver()
   registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter)
}
```

and my receiver is just

```
class StartupReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        MyService.start(context)
    }
}
```

```
fun start(context: Context){
   val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
   for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE)) {
      if (service.service.shortClassName.contains("MyService")) {
         return
      }
   }
   Intent(context, MyService::class.java).also {
      context.startService(it)
   }
}
```

```
<receiver
   android:name=".StartupReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:targetApi="n">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    
    
class StartupReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        val action = p1?.action
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

        // This is executed once the boot is completed
        // You may start you foreground service here

        }
    }
}
```

NB: From targetSdk 31, Service can be invoked only when the application is in the foreground. You can use the WorkManager to do the intended task instead.

Comment: No, boot already works, the non working intent is USER_PRESENT, I already have the needed permission